# How to partition large Redshift table into N smaller ones

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a very large table with 13.5 million rows. The table has the following columns:

| index | id | source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | A |
| 1 | 10 | B |
| 3 | 60 | A |
| 3 | 60 | B |

The index column although it is unique, it is not incremental as I have not figured out how to do that in Redshift.  The id column is not unique.

I want to partition the table into 14 tables such that each table has a unique set of rows and no table has more than 1 million rows.

Also rows with the same ID value but from different sources need to be within the same table.

Comment: why though? 13.5 million is not at all large.

Comment: It's a constraint for the product i'm working on. It is not able to read 13.5 million rows at once.

Comment: Why does your product attempt to read all values from the database? It should send a query to retrieve the specific information it needs. In fact, you could do that in a query, such as `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY index LIMIT 1000000 OFFSET 3000000` -- this would read 1m values from the table, skipping the first 3m rows. You could call it repeatedly with a different `OFFSET` to retrieve the data in sets. However, there's probably a much better way to achieve your end-goal but you'd need to tell us what your application is doing with that data, to see if there's a better option.

Comment: I do appreciate that there's probably a much better a way to do this but at the moment it is not possible to make any changes. That's why I'm wondering how I can do this on Redshift. It is already working with PostgreSQL and now we are trying to replicate the process on Redshift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create smaller tables from the larger table with a 'CREATE TABLE AS'.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_AS.html

```
CREATE TABLE smaller1 AS 
SELECT index, id, source FROM bigtable WHERE id = [subset 1 of ids that is less than one million records];
...
CREATE TABLE smaller2 AS 
SELECT index, id, source FROM bigtable WHERE id = [subset 2 of ids that is less than one million records]
..etc..
```

One option is to use the `MOD` operator which would put rows with the same id value in the same table, but does require an even distribution of id values, and may not exactly be how you want to partition the big table:

```
CREATE TABLE smaller1 AS 
SELECT index, id, source FROM bigtable WHERE MOD(myidx, 14) = 0;
```